# I'm facing problem in retriving cookies.get() value in reactjs, it shows me undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux

When I try to retrive cookie value from localhost.

```
cookies.set('token', payload.token, {maxAge: 3600_000,secure:true, domain:'http://localhost:3001' })

cookies.set("user", JSON.stringify(payload.user),{maxAge: 3600_000,secure:true, domain: 'http://localhost:3001' })

//get cookie value undefine
console.log("Login success token",  cookies.get('token'))
```

My cookies storage output
[image]

what is happening with my code I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In the image you can see the cookie has a field `HttpOnly: true`. When this field is set to true it is not possible to retrieve cookies in the frontend using JS. Here you can read a bit more about this field https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly

This field is useful as it protects your site against XSS attacks

Comment: How could I do cookies based authentication here from frontend ?

Comment: There are many ways to do authentication with JWT cookies. Personally I like using refresh and access tokens. You can check out this blog that has a guide explaining this https://blog.garethlau.me/posts/token-authentication. Also, httpOnly cookies get sent on every request so just having one cookie as httpOnly can protect you from XSS attacks but leave you open to CSRF attacks. The blog I linked has reference to a guide that explains in more detail